# Should cohort studies in diagnosis research be age-matched?

Tags: matching, predictor, case-control-study, case-cohort

It is clear that cohort studies in epidemiology should be matched for such variables as age, gender, etc.

However, cross-sectional cohort studies may also be used to assess the accuracy of a new diagnostic test (compared to a reference standard). In such a design, all patients (or a random sample thereof) presenting to their doctor would receive both the new diagnostic test and the reference standard. In that case, should participants be matched for any variable? My intuition says no but I'd like to have your opinion (ideally with a reference).

Answer (score 1):

The only time I would use matching is if we have too few observations to do covariate adjustment, or if not all the data are yet sampled and you want to save money by not sampling too many subjects who are not very informative for the main estimand (e.g. case-control study).

Cohort studies in epidemiology do not at all need to be matched.  You need to model variables having to do with outcome heterogeneity.

For diagnostic studies, standard statistical regression models are the best way to assess diagnostic yield.  See Chapter 19 of [Biostatistics for Biomedical Research](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/ClinStat).

Comment: What about studies investigating diagnostic accuracy? Should any covariate be taken into account? I believe not. Here is my understanding of why through an example. If patients who actually are having a stroke tend to be older than other patients with neurological symptoms presenting to A&E, then (i) age is simply part of the diagnosis itself and does not need to be added as a covariate, (ii) age will affect both the performance of the reference diagnostic test and that of the new diagnostic test so that the reported performance will not be biased. Is there any flow in this reasoning?

Comment: I don't agree with that way of looking at it.  See my expanded answer.

Comment: @Frank Harrell Do you have any references handy arguing covariate adjustment works better than matching? Thanks.

Comment: There are papers out there; the only ones to come to mind right now deal with propensity matching vs. covariate adjustment for logit propensity score.  What matters is the mean squared error and mean absolute error of the final estimator.  With matching one tends to hide interaction effects, lose observations, have inexact adjustment, and create arbitrariness.  I've discussed this in Chapter 10 of Biostatistics for Biomedical Research at http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/ClinStat .  For papers on propensity matching/adjustment see http://www.citeulike.org/user/harrelfe/tag/propensity-score .