# How should age be handled when obtaining a diagnostic biomarker signature?

Tags: roc, diagnostic

I wonder if anyone can advise me on how the issue of age should be handled when identifying diagnostic biomarkers, combining them (e.g. via logistic regression, lasso) to obtain a signature to improve diagnostic ability and obtaining a valid estimate of diagnostic ability (e.g. AUC) maybe in a fresh diagnostic data set.

Are there any good explanations or sources on best practice?

I'd imagine we develop a signature using biomarker values from diseased cases (maybe a few groups representing stage) vs healthy controls.

So there are a number of issues:

1) Should we age match (and maybe gender match) the healthy controls and cases? It may be the case that the levels of some of the biomarkers vary with age and also that cases if sampled randomly would be older than controls.

2) Should the strategy for question 1) depend on some test or evaluation in the data of whether the biomarkers vary by age (although if we already have the data it may be too late)

3) Should we include age (and gender) as a candidate predictor in the diagnostic signature (i.e. the weighted sum of biomarkers obtained by logistic regression or lasso etc.)

4) Should the validation data set also be age (and gender) matched?

Answer (score 1):

I think Prof Harrell is saying here lack of matching doesn't matter as long as age is included as a covariate in the signature ? [Should cohort studies in diagnosis research be age-matched?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195085/should-cohort-studies-in-diagnosis-research-be-age-matched)

Comment: Need to separate modeling from biomarker evaluation.  Evaluation needs to show added value over above age, sex, and the clinical variables that are commonly used.  When modeling it's often the case that the demographic + clinical + continuous biomarker model is developed without distinguishing which variables are 'new' or 'old'.

Comment: many thanks for the comments, I wonder if we'd compare diagnostic ability (AUC) of a clinical (age, gender) model versus clinical+biomarkers - I know reclassification metrics can be used to assess additional prediction but I thought their usefullness wasn't established and that they were more relevant to prognosis than diagnosis